# Dynamically style components passed as props

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

The goal is to style a prop inside a function (if the prop exists).

More specifically, I basically pass an icon (from `styled-icons`) as a prop to it and it is supposed to add styling to that icon.

This works with warnings:

```js
const InputRounded = ({ type, placeholder, icon }) => {
  const Icon = styled(icon)`
    color: #807da0;
    width: 1.75rem;
    margin: 0 1.25rem 0 0.75rem;
  `

  return (
    <Container>
      <Input type={type} placeholder={placeholder} />
      <Icon />
    </Container>
  )
}
```

Here is how I call it:

```
import { LockPassword } from '@styled-icons/remix-line'

<Input type="password" placeholder="Password" icon={LockPassword} />
```

I am aware that one shouldn't create a component inside a function, but I have tried numerous ways otherwise and haven't reached anywhere. Any help for a better method would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, very simply, pass a `style` prop to `icon`.

```
const InputRounded = ({ type, placeholder, icon: Icon }) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Input type={type} placeholder={placeholder} />
      <Icon style={{ color: '#807da0', ... }} />
    </Container>
  )
}
```

Comment: This works great, thanks!  
One question, could you explain the `icon: Icon` syntax?

Comment: Just an alias (it allow you to give another name to that var). It's a common convention to have the name of components capitalised. But nothing prevent you from just calling it as `<icon` instead

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the cloneElement method in React

- https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement

```
return (
  <> 
    { React.cloneElement( icon, [props] }
  </>
)
```

It is similar to

`<element.type {...element.props} {...props}>{children}</element.type>`

To override some values you can do inline styling.

or otherwise you could use some css classes to override with selectors as well.

- if you are going to use `styled-icons`
- you can just simply provide it the props directly.
- Styled Icons accept all the valid props of an `<svg />` element

https://github.com/styled-icons/styled-icons#props